# How to create a reflexive relationship that points to the same table in ERBuilder

Tags: database, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I am using [ERBuilder data modeler](https://soft-builder.com/en/erbuilder-data-modeler/), I have created tables with their primary keys and I have created relationships between tables.
but the problem that i have, I can't find how to create a Foreign Key relationship that points to the same table (reflexive relationship).

Comment: Try adding what you have done so far to make this a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, try adding a [minimal, reproductive example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it more clear what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just right click on the table and click on "reflexive relationship".